# Creating a derived object from an existing base object in .net

Tags: .net

Dumb question.

Lets say I have a bunch of person objects with their fields all filled in with data and I have an employee type that derives from the person class and has extra fields related to being an employee.  How do I get a employee object for a particular existing person object?  i.e. How do I pass in the person object to the employee?

Comment: Why is the answer the case? 

I dont see why you can't just cast person to an employee. If it is the base class, all the base class fields would have to be there?

Am I misssing something obvious why this can't be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the person was created as an employee, then just cast:

```
Person person = new Employee(); // for some reason
...
Employee emp = (Employee)person;
```

If the person is just a person: you can't; you could have the employee *encapsulate* the Person - or you can *copy* the fields:

```
class Employee { // encapsulation
  private readonly Person person;
  public Person {get {return person;}}
  public Employee(Person person) {this.person = person;}
  public Employee() : this(new Person()) {}
}
```

or

```
class Employee : Person { // inheritance
  public Employee(Person person) : base(person) {}
  public Employee() {}
}
class Person {
    public Person(Person template) {
        this.Name = template.Name; // etc
    }
    public Person() {}
}
```